# Is this sentence grammatically correct and can be used for Women's Day?

Tags: meaning, grammar, phrases, conjunctions, grammatical-gender

> Let women rise and use their strength to contribute to the world.

I need to use this sentence for a Women's Day social media design. But there are two doubts:

1. Should it be wom**e**n or wom**a**n?
2. Let women rise *and use their strength*

In 2nd doubt, one may feel that I want to say "Let women rise and **take benefit** from their strength and **use** it. But what I actually mean to say is:

Let us allow her to **RISE AND USE THEIR STRENGTH** i.e., let her do both things.

So can it be fixed or is it already understood?

Comment: Grammatically there is nothing wrong with your sentence – it’s grammatical, understandable, and quite clear. Beyond that, when we start getting into morality and what is the right thing to say, we start moving too far into opinions for the question to be on topic here, I fear.

Comment: Actually by morally, I just wanted to make sure it shouldn't be insulting or absurd for women. What you say now?

Comment: Please somebody reply